# Having trouble running NetLogo models using parLapply

Tags: r, parallel-processing, netlogo

I'm trying to run a NetLogo simulation (using RNetLogo package) in R using parallel processing on my laptop.  I'm trying to assess "t-feeding of females" using 3 (i.e., 0, 25, and 50) different "minimum-separation" values.  For each "minimum-separation" value, I'd like to replicate the simulation 10 times. I can run everything correctly just using `lapply` but I'm having trouble with `parLapply`.  I've just started using the package "parallel" so I'm sure it is something in the syntax.

```
#Set up clusters for parallel
processors <- detectCores()
cl <- makeCluster(processors)

#Simulation
sim3 <- function(min_sep) {
 NLCommand("set minimum-separation ", min_sep, "setup")
 ret <- NLDoReport(720, "go", "[t-feeding] of females", as.data.frame=TRUE)
 tot <- sum(ret[,1])
 return(tot)
}  

#Replicate simulations 10 times using lapply and create boxplots.  This one works.
rep.sim3 <- function(min_sep, rep) {
 return(
 lapply(min_sep, function(min_sep) {
 replicate(rep, sim3(min_sep))
 })
 )
}
d <- seq(0,50,25)
res <- rep.sim3(d,10)
boxplot(res,names=d, xlab="Minimum Separation", ylab="Time spent feeding")

#Replicate simulations 10 times using parLapply.  This one does not work.
rep.sim3 <- function(min_sep, rep) {
 return(
 parLapply(cl, min_sep, function(min_sep) {
 replicate(rep, sim3(min_sep))
 })
 )
}
d <- seq(0,50,25)
res <- rep.sim3(d,10)

# Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 3 nodes produced errors; first error: could not find function "sim3"

#Replicate simulations 10 times using parLapply.  This one does work but creates a list of the wrong length and therefore the boxplot cannot be plotted correctly.
rep.sim3 <- function(min_sep, rep) {
 return(
 parLapply(cl, replicate(rep, d), sim3))
}
d <- seq(0,50,25)
res <- rep.sim3(d,10)
```

Ideally I'd like to make the first `parLapply` work.  Alternatively, I guess I could modify `res` from the `parLapply` that works so that the list has a length of `max_sep` instead of 30.  However, I can't seem to do that.  Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to initialize the cluster workers before executing `rep.sim3`.  The error message indicates that your workers can't execute the `sim3` function because you haven't exported it to them.  Also, I noticed that you haven't loaded the `RNetlogo` package on the workers, either.

The easiest way to initialize the workers is with the `clusterEvalQ` and `clusterExport` functions:

```
clusterEvalQ(cl, library(RNetLogo))
clusterExport(cl, 'sim3')
```

Note that you shouldn't do this in your `rep.sim3` function, since that would be inefficient and unnecessary.  Do it just once after creating the cluster object and `sim3` has been defined.

This initialization is necessary because the workers started via `makeCluster` don't know anything about your variables or functions, or anything else about your R session.  And `parLapply` doesn't analyze the function that you pass to it any more than `lapply` does.  The difference is that `lapply` executes in your local R session where `sim3` is defined and the `RNetLogo` package is loaded.  `parLapply` executes the specified function in remote R sessions that have not been initialized by executing your R script.